# Numpy FFT over few seconds

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm trying to understand how fft in python works (or in general).
When I have a signal that is recorded for a few seconds I can only display one second of that FFT.
Is there a way to take all of the data and averaged this out?
I did this before in LabView.
Can any one help?

Here is an example code that I'm using.

```
from numpy import linspace, sin, pi, log10, average, arange
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, figure
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq

N = 1000 * 60 * 4
dt = 1 / 1000
x = linspace(0, N*dt, N)
freq = linspace(10, 200, N)
sinsweep = sin(x*freq)
mavg = [average(sinsweep[i*60:(i+1)*60]) for i in range(int(N/60))]
plot(freq, sinsweep, '.')
plot(linspace(10, 200, int(N/60)), mavg, '.')

f = figure()
t = arange(60)
sp = fft(mavg, n=60)
freq = fftfreq(t.shape[-1])
plot(sp.imag)
show()
```

[image: plot data]
[image: fft]

Comment: I don't get what you are trying t do. What is your expected output. The code you use does work. It takes the mean signal within a second and displays multiple seconds.

Comment: I'm trying to get a fft graph that shows for the duration of all of the test all of the frequencies. Meaning that I shold get a wide range from 10 to 200 Hz.

Comment: Then take the FFT of the signal and you are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give some modification to your code, to obtain a beautiful spectrum. First I increase the number of points to verify Shannon criterion. And some tricks to
improve speed.

```
from numpy import linspace, sin, pi, log10, average, arange
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, figure
from numpy.fft import fft, fftfreq
close()
N = 10000 * 60 * 4
dt = 1 / 10000
t = arange(0, N*dt, dt)
freq = linspace(10, 200, N)
sinsweep = sin(t*freq)
mavg = sinsweep.reshape(-1,60).mean(1)
tm=t[::60]
figure('signal')
plot(tm, mavg)    
sp = fft(mavg)
freq = fftfreq(tm.size,dt*60)
valid=freq>0
figure('spectrum')
plot(freq[valid],abs(sp[valid]))
show()
```

for[image]

Is it what you expected ?

Comment: Yes,Thank you. But I don't understand how does the FFT program know what frequency I'm working? If it calculates all of the data it may assume that the data is at 1Hz? And one more question what are the units in the Y, if the input is lets say m? Thank you again.

Comment: Te (sampling) is 1/dt,  total time is t_max-t_min. Y is not normalized : you must divide it by (N/2) to have the good magnitude.  your 'mean' (/60) don't ease to speak about all of that.